# Correct style for chained list expressions in Python

Tags: python, styles, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a simple query over an array of objects in Python that would be trivial and elegant in C# or Ruby, but I'm having a hard time making it elegant in Python. I figure I'm doing something wrong.

In C#:

```
list.Where(x => x.Foo > 10).Select(x => x.Bar).Where(x => x.Baz.StartsWith("/"))
```

This will create an enumeration including `list[0].Bar` providing `list[0].Foo` > 10 and `list[0].Bar.Baz` starts with `'/'`, and so on for all the other items in list. The data flows clearly from left to right, and further filtering / projection / aggregation can be appended on the right.

In Ruby:

```
list.select { |x| x.foo > 10 }.map(&:bar).select { |x| x.baz.starts_with? '/' }
```

Again, it's a fairly clear flow from left to right, and further operations can be appended with ease.

But my attempts in Python seem backwards, inside out and generally ugly:

```
[x for x in (x.bar for x in (x for x in list if x.foo > 10)) if x.baz.startswith('/')]
```

Now I know I can combine a map and a filter in a single step with a list comprehension, and that the above could be rewritten as this:

```
[x.bar for x in list if x.foo > 10 and x.bar.baz.startswith('/')]
```

but that rather misses the point. For one thing, the projection x.bar may be expensive, and I don't want to evaluate it twice; for another, projection and filtering are only two of the potential operations I'm applying to the stream, I could be sorting, aggregating, paginating, etc., and not all projections and filters need be adjacent, nor the filter applying before the projection rather than after.

Am I trying to twist Python into something it's not? I generally try to program in this style whenever I can, whether it's the command-line (shell pipes), C#, Ruby, or Java (a lot more pain than Python). Should I stop poking where it hurts?

Comment: Python uses `if`, not `where`; `[x.bar for x in list if x.foo > 10 and x.bar.baz.startswith('/')]`

Comment: I don't mind you editing it, I just did anyhow.

Comment: If this is all numerical stuff you are doing, you can take a look at numpy.  You can do this sort of stuff, but in a functional way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator to produce the `bar` values; you had one unneeded generator level:

```
[bar for bar in (x.bar for x in somelist if x.foo > 10) if bar.baz.startswith('/')]
```

You can assign that nested generator to a variable first:

```
bars = (x.bar for x in somelist if x.foo > 10)
[bar for bar in bars if bar.baz.startswith('/')]
```

if you want to keep things within a line length limit. The generator will be consumed only once, accessing the expensive `.bar` attribute once only for each element of `somelist`.

You can take this further if you want to replicate the reading order of the C# and Ruby code, by using separate generators for the steps:

```
filtered_on_foo = (x for x in somelist if x.foo > 10)
bar_selected = (x.bar for x in filtered_on_foo)
filtered_on_baz = [bar for bar in bar_selected if bar.baz.startswith('/')]
```

but now you are incurring an extra loop by selecting separately.

Comment: OK; so it looks like I'm not missing anything, you do have to structure it inside out, and to make it linear you need to extract out the inside bit to a previous line, give the expression a name, then use the name later. Bummer.

Comment: @BarryKelly: You can create named generators too, one filtering or selecting from a previous one. The `bars` generator does two things at once, filtering and selecting.

Comment: I already knew everything you wrote; I could get that much from docs etc. What I didn't know was if there was a better way of chaining, specifically. I now know there almost certainly isn't.

Comment: @BarryKelly: The Python standard library does not use chaining. It's considered unpythonic, you usually avoid structuring your data where you are forced to chain altogether.

Comment: most of my programming tasks are most expressively encoded as linear data flows, whether compilers (last job) or financial reconciliation (current job). It's not the data structure that forces the chain; it's the data flow.

Comment: Sure, for SQL(like) data, chaining is often very natural. The SQLAlchemy library uses chaining throughout. It is not, however, part of the Python core datatypes philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm working as C# developer and I like LINQ very much (not as much as Python, though :) ), I've always wondered why there's no Python version of LINQ.

But I never had time to check this properly, because I'm using Python only for fun.
So after your question I've started to search is there anything like LINQ exists for Python (I've actually thinking about writing something like this by myself if there's no such a module exists).

I think this one is good - [A Python implementation of LINQ to objects and Parallel LINQ to objects (ASQ)](https://code.google.com/p/asq/):

For you case it could work like this:

```
from asq.initiators import query

a = [{"foo":1, "bar": {"baz":"aaaa"}}, {"foo": 11, "bar": {"baz":"/ddddd"}}]

q = query(a).where(lambda x: x["foo"] > 10).select(lambda x: x["bar"]).where(lambda x: x['baz'].startswith('/'))

q.to_list()
# gives [{'foo': 11, 'bar': {'baz': '/ddddd'}}]
```

The only downside I've found that it's not possible to format this query like this:

```
q = query(a).where(lambda x: x["foo"] > 10)
            .select(lambda x: x["bar"])
            .where(lambda x: x['baz'].startswith('/'))
```

You can also do this processing in functional style:

```
q = ifilter(lambda x: x["foo"] > 10, a)
q = imap(lambda x: x["bar"], q)
q = ifilter(lambda x: x["baz"].startswith('/'), q)
```